# Configuration dependes xxx configuration that will not exist after import

Tags: search, 10

I have this scenario that is basically the opposite of "it works on my machine" - mine is the only one where it doesn't work.

when running `drush cim` I get this error:

> In ConfigImportCommands.php line 324:
>
> The import failed due to the following reasons:
> Configuration *search_api.index.documents_index* depends on the *search_api.server.documents_server* configuration that will not exist after import.
> Configuration *search_api.index.products_index* depends on the *search_api.server.server_products* configuration that will not exist after import.

both indexes are to be imported, search_api is enabled at core.exetension.yml

```yml
  search: 0
  search_api: 0
  search_api_autocomplete: 0
  search_api_solr: 0
```

I can skip this error but commenting this line on search_api.index.documents_index.yml:

```yml
dependencies:
 config:
   (...)
   - search_api.server.server_products
```

As a result, the indexing of content won't succeed when uncommenting the line.

I get the same errors even after doing a `lando rebuild`.
it is Drupal 10 with Solr 8 and the search_api version is `"drupal/search_api": "^1.29"`

Comment: It sounds like a server has been created upstream/in other environments (possibly via UI), and not exported to config. If that’s the case, pull down a fresh database and do a config export to get the “server_products” config created, then your next import should work.

Comment: @Clive I got the dump from the original environment and exported the config zip file. It is a folder solr_8.x_config - where should I place it? as a folder within config/solr-config or as the content of config/solr-config? I've tried as the content of the folder, as a folder called solr_8.x_config and also called 8.0.0 - no success yet